# What is keeping my winforms app alive in processes after I closed and handled the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Given:
Visual Studio 2022 .Net 7
C# Winforms project template

I'm using Start Without Debug to start the program. I just noticed when I hit red x in corner it's not going into form_closed event. I guess my problem is what event does the red x in top corner right use?

What is keeping my winforms app alive in processes after I closed and handled the form?

```
namespace JKEventsPractice1123
{
    internal static class Program
    {


        static Button _button1 = new Button();

        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            _button1 = new Button();

            //but.Click += (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button"); };
            _button1.Click += Button1_Clicked;

            var form = new Form();
            form.Controls.Add(_button1);
            form.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }

        static void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button");


            _button1.Click -= Button1_Clicked;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1 code-behind

```
   private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        
    }
```

Comment: I cannot recreate problem with the code and information you provided. Are you sure it is all the information we need to recreate the problem?

Comment: it shows up further down (Background processes) the Task Manager processes (if sorted by Name) after I close it. But before that it will appear in top section (again, if sorted by name)

Comment: I know your problem. I have tested your code in my new temporary repository with exact your code but the process terminate normally when I close the form. That's why I think you need to provide more information in order for anyone to recreate your problem, for example, how was your project been build? what version of whatever you are using? what is the IDE you are using?

Comment: sorry, i updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `new Form()` which is base Form class. If your custom Form class is named `Form1` try with `new Form1()` instead .

Also you need to pass your form instance as argument like `Application.Run(form)` instead of `Application.Run()`. If you use `Application.Run` the form should show automatically and the application should exit when you close the form so you don't have to add `Application.Exit()` in `FormClosed` event.

## Example

```cs
// Program.cs
namespace DeleteMe;

static class Program
{
    static Button _button1 = new Button();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        _button1 = new Button();
        _button1.Click += Button1_Clicked;
        var form = new Form1();
        form.Controls.Add(_button1);
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    static void Button1_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button");
        _button1.Click -= Button1_Clicked;
    }
}
```

```cs
// Form1.cs
namespace DeleteMe;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```